# Nodejs http request does not call from recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a strange situation

I need send request 3 times or until I get correct response

```
var connect = function(){ 

  console.log('first step');

  var connector = http.request(some_options, function(resp) {

    console.log('sec step');

    resp.on("data", function(chunk){
        str += chunk;
    });
    resp.on("end", function() {

      console.log('third step');

      if (resp.statusCode != 200){
        return false
      }
      else{
        var rep = 3;
        var i = 1;
        (function retry_connect(){                                          
           if ((i <= rep) && JSON.parse(str).hasOwnProperty('error')) {
             console.log('reconnect');
             connect();
             i++;
             setTimeout(function(){retry_connect()}, 3000);                             
           }
           else{
             return true
           }
        }());
      }
    });
  });
};

connect();
```

Output of this code here:

```
first step
sec step
third step
reconnect
first step
first step
first step
```

Can explain why connector does not called from retry_connect() function?

Thanks

Comment: That is, umm, interesting. Are you sure it's not called from somewhere else? You could try a `console.trace()` instead of the `console.log('first step')`

Comment: Have you tried closing the request before starting a new one?

Comment: Oh, yes. I tried it, but I think I did it in the wrong block of code. I did it after `console.log('reconnect')`. After I closed connection outside of closure, script run correctly. Thanks for idea!

Answer (score 0):

your http.request might emit an error,
try to add:

```
connector.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
```

btw. your return statements wont do a thing might as well omit them

also http.request is an async function, (thus the return from connect is async)
you iterate i...rep and recursively call connect() and set a timeout to call retry_connect
for a total of 3 times, which in turn will do the same, but now 3 times more etc. etc.

ill asume your interested in the total response body

```
function connect (opts, callback, count) {

    if (count > 3) {
        console.log('retry limit reached');
        callback({error:'retry limit reached'});
    } else {
        var request = http.request(opts, function (response) {
            var buffer = [];

            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                buffer.push(chunk);
            });
            response.on('end', function () {
                var data = buffer.join('');
                if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                    console.log('did not receive a 200 OK');
                    callback({error: {statusCode: response.statusCode}});
                } else {
                    //200 OK but the json data might contain an error
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (parsed.error) {
                        count = (count||0) +1;
                        console.log('retrying in ' + (count * 3000));
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            console.log('retrying now');
                            connect(opts, callback, count);
                        }, 3000 * count);
                    } else {
                        console.log('200 OK and no error in json, calling callback with parsed json response');
                        callback(null, parsed);
                    }
                }
            });

        });

        request.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log('request error', error);
            callback({error:error});
        });
    }

}

connect({host: 'example.com'}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('something went wrong:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('request done:', data);
    }
});
```

since all this is asynchrnous youll need some mechanism to be able to signal back when things are done/failed, ive used an callback to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using callback in my script and this method seemed more appropriate. But also I had to consider closing the connection before starting a new one.

Comment: Please tell me why this method does not work on POST requests?

Comment: do you have an example? request.write(...) and request.end() should work just fine (add them after the request.on('error'...) after you've called request.end the request will be processed